# Feynman diagram and uncertainty

Tags: quantum-field-theory, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, feynman-diagrams

I have been introduced to the Feynman diagrams in QFT after following Wick-Dyson tedious formalism.

Two things are unclear, though, about the Feynman shortcut to compute scattering amplitudes.

What are the horizontal and vertical axes in these diagrams? Are they $x$ and $t$ respectively or $x$ and $y$?

If yes then we are drawing a particle with an exact momentun $p$.

But doesn't this violate the uncertainty principle since we are assuming exactly measured $x$ and $p$?

Comment: At each vertex of Feynman diagrams momentum conservation is ensured by Dirac delta function.

Comment: I mean consider an external leg in the Feynman diagram. Are both momentum and position exactly measured?

Comment: Normally, the external legs represent momentum states of the particles, so their position is undetermined. As @AccidentalFourierTransform points out in their answer, position on a Feynman diagram does not represent position or time. The graph connections are what matter - not the locations of the nodes.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are no axes in Feynman diagrams. The only important part of a diagram is what is connected to what, and not the relative orientation. You can move around the pieces of a diagram and, as long as you don't break any line, the value of the diagram remains unchanged.

Comment: This. If one wants a formal statement, a Feynman diagram is an isomorphism class of a certain kind of graphs, and these graphs are not to be thought to be embedded in anything.

Comment: @ACuriousMind the problem is, many introductions to QFT insist in "time flowing from left to right" in Feynman diagrams, which is of no help, not even to a beginner. I have no idea why people perpetuate this.

Comment: So the vertical axe is not anything. But you see Wikipedia puts the horizontal axe as $t$ to say as if anti particles move backward?

Comment: @VictorVMotti see my comment above: Wikipedia, as many other informal sources (e.g., many professors), insist in the lie to the children that a Feynman diagram represents a physical process. You will have people tell you that time flows from top to bottom or statements of the sort. But you will know better: that is false. A Feynman diagram is a device to organise Wick contractions, and nothing else.

Comment: Can you show what do you by mean move around the pieces of the diagram? Are you suggesting to rotate it?

Comment: @VictorVMotti rotate it. Or take one line and move its origin to any other point in the plane. Or take a vertex and move it up/down. Or take a line and bend it. Do whatever you want with the pieces.

Comment: So anti particle moving to the past is also incorrect or a mere interpretation.

Comment: @VictorVMotti I would call it a mnemonic rule. Nothing really moves to the past, but thinking that an antiparticle behaves *as* it were a particle moving backwards in time helps to remember some properties of particles and antiparticles, such as that they have opposite charge, opposite helicity, they are related by the time reversal operator, etc.

Comment: This isn't really true - there *is* a time axis (but not a space or momentum axis). If you re-organize the outgoing legs and you change in which time direction they flow out you might get the same amplitude, but you change the processes to which it is applicable. Also, note how (for a vertical time axis) no legs can exit the diagram horizontally? That's because the time axis does matter.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty that depends on what one means by a Feynman diagram. It may be an S matrix element or a correlation function. For the latter, there are no in- and out-states and there are no axes. For the former, one may organise the in- and out-states by the convention that the particles to the left (or bottom) of the diagrams are incoming, and those to the right (or top) are out-going. But this doesnt mean that such an axis represents the flow of time, because the parts of the diagram dont represent what physically happens: it is not a frame-by-frame picture of the physical process.

Comment: For sure it is not a frame-by-frame picture of any physical process, but pretending that the time direction of the external legs has no meaning (which is implied by your answer) doesn't help.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty quite the contrary: insisting in pretending that there *is* a time direction in the diagram doesn't help. I guess we are gonna have to agree to disagree :-) I not only *imply* that the time direction of external legs has no meaning, but I *reaffirm* it. I hope one day people will stop using a time arrow in Feynman diagrams. There are different schools of thoughts about this, and maybe in the end your interpretation is more useful. But I am quite convinced that it is not...

Answer (score 8):

You have to realize that the Feynman diagram is a schematic representation of the integrals of the scattering amplitude , necessary to calculate the integral for that order. All variables will be integrated within the limits of the integral, so it is not a real space and time but an iconic one seen in a Feynman diagram. The result is a crossection, or a lifetime for that interaction, or an angular distribution. Quantum mechanical probabilities are all there.

Comment: Yes I see. But the diagrams looks like they are showing the scattering process in time at least. Right?

Comment: time and space on the diagram are iconal, standing in for  the time and space in the integrals which are variables